# Need help in login redirect using asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication

I have problem with Login page.If i dont enter the Username or password it should say that"please enter a Username or password" instead its going to destination page i mean without entering anything in Login field if i hit submit button its going to welcome page actually which should not happen.

Here is my code please somebody tell me where is my mistake:

```
public class Login
{
  public string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    public int GetLogin(string UserName, string Password)
    {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Login where UserName='"+UserName+"' and Password='"+Password+"'",con);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if ((ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString() == UserName) && (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString() == Password))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
Login.aspx.cs:
protected void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = TxtUserName.Text;      

        Login lg = new Login();    

        if ((lg.GetLogin(TxtUserName.Text, TxtPassword.Text) == 1))
        {
            Response.Redirect("c1.aspx");

        }

        else if((TxtUserName.Text=="")&&(TxtPassword.Text==""))
        {
            Lbl1.Text = "Please Enter the UserName and Password";
        }

        else
        {

            Lbl1.Text = "Sorry,Invalid UserName or Password";
        }             

    }
```

Comment: You know there's a login control that handles all this in ASP.NET right?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is cool sometimes! NOT in this case, though.

Answer (score 5):

All of this functionality is already built in to ASP.NET.

Check out [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) to validate your fields, or use [Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) to handle all the form functionality for you.

Check out [FormsAuthentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx) and [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) for user authentication.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really know what the problem is, because it looks like it should work, but you have a huge SQL injection issue.  Test this out on a test database but enter this for your UserName.

```
' and 1 = 1; drop table Login; --
```

May I suggest you look up SqlParameter and do a search for "SqlParameter SQL Injection Attack"

Answer (score 1):

1.- the user and pass empty validations are after the db call so  if you have a blank user with a blank password the login will succedd

2.- you are creating the sql query this is open to sql injection, please use parametrized queries.

Comment: Yet it's the No.2 that's the real problem. *frowns worriedly*